# Fundamental matrix of ODE system $\dot{x} = (At+B)x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-dynamics

Suppose I have a system of ODEs $\dot{x} = (At+B)x$, where $x(t)$ is a, say, $n \times 1$ vector, and $A$ and $B$ are constant $n \times n$ matrices. What is the fundamental matrix of this system?

I tried $e^{\frac{At^2}{2}}e^{Bt}$, trying to emulate the one-dimensional solution, but then A and B don't necessarily commute for it to work. Do I need the Lie bracket $[A,B] = AB - BA$ somewhere? Do I need something like power series?

Comment: You can't expect an answer in terms of elementary functions, since (for example) if $At+B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ t & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ the system is equivalent to the Airy equation $\ddot x_1(t) = t \, x_1(t)$, with Airy functions as solutions. But maybe you could try looking for a solution in the form of a power series?